# Excel - How to select (random) n rows whose total is less than or equal to X

Tags: excel

I have a dataset of 100,000 rows, and I'm trying to select n rows that add to be less than or euqal to X.

For example, I'd like 10 random rows that add up to less then or equal to 10,000

Thank you

The only solution that I have found is add a =RAND() column, create a pivot table, filter top 10 and keep refreshing the table until the total of the 10 rows is less then 10,000.

Comment: Isn't that a [Solver](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/define-and-solve-a-problem-by-using-solver-5d1a388f-079d-43ac-a7eb-f63e45925040) problem?

Comment: This can be done, and it's probably simpler to do in Excel O365 than without.  What version are you running.  And importantly, your selected rows may be *scattered about* but most decidedly *not* be "random."  Accepting right up front that the sections will not actually be random opens the doors for a number of techniques.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the replies.

I tried solver, and I get too many variable cells error. 

I'm using Excel 2019 and yes, they can be scattered. Thank you